dense point cloud .ply transformation from WGS84(epsg:4978) to projected CRS(epsg:2227) shows incorrect result
I'm working on re-projecting dense point cloud (.ply) from WGS to projected CRS using python fails to generate similar result to the original poin cloud data. Instead on viewer result shows points in z direction. All I was doing is transforming vertices (x,y). Is there something more that needs to be done to achieve CRS conversion? appriciate help.
import os

import numpy as np
import pyproj
from plyfile import PlyData, PlyElement

def read_point_cloud(file_path):
    """Read point cloud data from a PLY file."""
    plydata = PlyData.read(file_path)
    vertices = np.vstack((plydata['vertex']['x'], plydata['vertex']['y'], plydata['vertex']['z'])).T
    return plydata, vertices

def write_point_cloud(plydata, file_path):
    """Write the updated point cloud data to a PLY file."""
    plydata.write(file_path)

def convert_projection(vertices, original_proj, target_proj):
    """Convert the coordinates of the point cloud vertices from one projection to another."""
    transformer = pyproj.Transformer.from_proj(original_proj, target_proj, always_xy=True)
    converted_vertices = []
    for point in vertices:
        lon, lat, z = point
        new_lon, new_lat = transformer.transform(lon, lat)
        converted_vertices.append([new_lon, new_lat, z])
    return np.array(converted_vertices)

# Example usage
if __name__ == "__main__":
 
    # Get the directory path of the current file
    file_directory = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

    # Use the file_directory variable as needed
    input_file = os.path.join(file_directory, "dense_point_cloud.ply")
    output_file = os.path.join(file_directory, "output_point_cloud.ply")

    # Define original and target projections
    original_proj = pyproj.Proj("epsg:4978")  # WGS 84 projection
    target_proj = pyproj.Proj("epsg:2227")    # Web Mercator projection

    
    print(input_file)
    print(output_file)
    
    # Read point cloud data
    plydata, vertices = read_point_cloud(input_file)

    # Convert coordinates
    converted_vertices = convert_projection(vertices, original_proj, target_proj)

    # Replace original vertices with projected vertices
    plydata['vertex']['x'] = converted_vertices[:, 0]
    plydata['vertex']['y'] = converted_vertices[:, 1]
    plydata['vertex']['z'] = converted_vertices[:, 2]

    # Write transformed point cloud data to file
    write_point_cloud(plydata, output_file)


